# What does (*s mean in OCaml?

Tags: comments, ocaml

I'm looking at an OCaml source file that begins like this

```
(*s Implementation of n-ary trees. (Some code is borrowed from the OCaml
    standard library, which is copyright 1996 INRIA.) *)
```

What does `(*s` mean? I thought the `s` might be a typo, but it appears in several files, so it must be deliberate.

Comment: Regular ocamldoc uses `(** ... *)` doc comments. The above looks like a doc comment, I vaguely remember there is some other documentation extractor out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(*s` is apparently used by [ocamlweb](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ocamlweb/), a [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) tool for OCaml (see https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ocamlweb/ocamlweb-1.38-man.html).

Comment: Great, thanks Virgile. `(*s` is of those things that's really hard to google for!

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in ocaml.

Everything inside `(*  *)` are comments.

May be it must be a convention used by them.